# MySQL result is 0 even though I can see it in the table

Tags: mysql

Hi all I've got an interesting problem I've never come across, but it seems to be something that crops up here every so often, however none are exactly like my situtation.

I have a table in MySQL that holds supplier data which is imported from a .csv

I then match the product by the supplier code.

However, in doing this I am not receiving a match, even though I can see the expected result in the table.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  `dealer` ,  `qty` 
FROM  `supplier_import_all` 
WHERE  `supplier_id` =  '13'
AND  `supplier_code` =  'DIGITAL979'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

And the MySQL result message:

> MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took
>   0.0027 sec )

This isn't right, I can see the entry in the table in PHPMyAdmin:

[image]

Any ideas on this one would be really appreciated as I am stumped.

---

Added the following before inserting into the database and it appears to have fixed the problem:

```
$supplier_code = str_replace(' ', '', $supplier_code);
$supplier_code = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $supplier_code);
```

Still interested to know why trim did not work tho, cos I am sure it must just be white spacing somewhere around the data, which has been reaffirmed by others here.

Comment: you have data issue. Just investigate it.

Answer (score 1):

It will help if you have your show create table.

It seems that you have bad or extra data in the column.

Try this

`SELECT  dealer ,  qty 
FROM  supplier_import_all
WHERE trim(supplier_id) =  '13'
AND  trim(supplier_code) =  'DIGITAL979'
LIMIT 0 , 30`

If this does not work try this
`SELECT  dealer ,  qty 
FROM  supplier_import_all
WHERE trim(supplier_id) =  '13'
LIMIT 0 , 30`

And if that works try this

`SELECT  dealer ,  qty 
FROM  supplier_import_all
WHERE trim(supplier_code) =  'DIGITAL979'
LIMIT 0 , 30`

This will help you identify which column has the bad data. 
Often when you import data from files extra spaces/charecaters are added.

Edited
Since we now know the issue with with the suplier_code column.  Try to fix that data in that column.
Try this 
`
Update  supplier_import_all
Set supplier_code = trim(supplier_code);

Update  supplier_import_all
Set supplier_code = trim(both "\t" from supplier_code);

Update  supplier_import_all
Set supplier_code = trim(both "\n" from supplier_code);
`

Comment: That did not work. But removing the "supplier_code" did. So yes bad data in there somewhere, would this likely be the table itself, or actually data in this column?

Comment: It would be a data in that column. Try to do this ` select concat('"', supplier_code, '"') from supplier_import_all` And see what vales does that give you   Check the value after the first double quote and the value before the last quote.

Comment: the above updates returned 0 results, the query above returned all the results like this: "DIGITAL979"

Comment: Can you please show the output of `show create table suplier_import_all` also is it possible for you to create a SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com) with some data where suplier_id ='13'

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure supplier_code does not have any spaces in it? This could sometimes happen, when you import from csv. Look up that record by a primary key, if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there may be some extra space stored in database which is not there while querying the same pl try using like operator and see if problem still persists if yes,than that's really strange

Comment: Yer, even attempting: SELECT * 
FROM  `supplier_import_all` 
WHERE  `supplier_code` LIKE  '%FS-510N%'
LIMIT 0 , 30 I get 0 results

Comment: Even add trim() to each of the vars before they are added to the database to ensure no extra whitespace

Answer (score 0):

`13` is right aligned in the column, which means that it is probably a number type, not a text type. Try

```
...
WHERE  `supplier_id` = 13 AND ...
```

(Without string delimiters around `13`)

Comment: no issue selecting by the `supplier_id`, just the `supplier_code`